# How to get the full path of a file in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like an easy way to get the full path to a file. I currently type this:

```
echo `pwd`/file.ext
```

Trying to shorten it, I made a bash alias:

```
alias fp='echo `pwd`/'
```

But now if I type `fp file.ext`, there is a space that appears between the `/` and the `file.ext`.

Does such a command already exist, and I am missing it? If not, how would I go about creating such an alias or function in bash?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

On linux systems, you should have `readlink` from the GNU coreutils project installed and can do this:

```
readlink -f file.ext
```

Debian/ubuntu systems may have the [realpath](http://packages.debian.org/sid/realpath) utility installed which "provides mostly the same functionality as `/bin/readlink -f` in the coreutils package."

Comment: `readlink -f` (or `realpath`, which is an older utility kept for compatibility) will additionally expand all symbolic links, which is not necessarily desirable.

Comment: fyi: does not work on macosx.

Comment: On my mac, I've installed coreutils using [homebrew](https://brew.sh) and it includes `realpath`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
realpath file.ext
```

Comment: I don't have that one. Where does that come from?

Comment: @frabjous: it's specific to Debian and derivatives, and will only be installed if you have requested it or a package that depends on it.

Comment: I'm using Arch. That's not Debian based, but there's a package for it in the AUR anyway. Not sure it's worth installing if I already have readlink though.

Comment: Well, that's an option; or you may consider a function, see [Gilles](http://superuser.com/questions/202645/bash-command-for-full-path-to-a-file/202728#202728)' answer. Anyway that depends on the real use you want to do with that (I'm curious).

Comment: @frabjous: You didn't specify what system you're on, but if it uses an Aptitude-based package manager (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, etc.), you can type `apt-cache search realpath` to reveal that the _coreutils_ and plain ol' _realpath_ packages both contain it. You can then type `sudo apt-get install realpath` (or `coreutils`) to install it.

Comment: @MichaelScheper Actually, I did. Really the follow up comments.

Comment: On MacOS you can get realpath via homebrew:  `brew install coreutils`

Answer (score 12):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3915420/5795941

This is the only way that is acceptable to me.  Doesn't expand links like realpath and readlink and is the classical way of doing it that I've seen all over.

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd -P)/$(basename "$1")"
```

Comment: This is the way to go when `$1` can be either a relative or an absolute path

Answer (score 10):

Instead of the `pwd` command, use the `PWD` variable (it's in POSIX as well):

```
fp () {
  case "$1" in
    /*) printf '%s\n' "$1";;
    *) printf '%s\n' "$PWD/$1";;
  esac
}
```

If you need to support Windows, recognizing absolute paths will be more complicated as each port of unix tools has its own rules for translating file paths. With Cygwin, use the `cygpath` utility.

Comment: Maybe it's your choice but this function won't output the new line.

Comment: this approach has the advantage of using only shell-builtins, which is faster than to call external binaries. you should make this fact a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 4):

to answer your question with what you use right now:

the alias expands at the position where you are typing right now. you typed:

```
% fp<SPACE>file.ext
```

this becomes

```
% echo `pwd`<SPACE>file.exe
```

you could use a function to avoid that:

```
function fp() {
    echo `pwd`/"$1"
}
```

you can use that as usual:

```
% fp file.ext
```

Comment: You need double quotes around variable and command substitutions: `echo "\`pwd\`/$1"`

Comment: @Gilles: under what circumstances?

Comment: @akira: Always use double quotes unless you want the result of the expansion to be treated as a globbing pattern and the results of globbing to be split into words. Here you're building a single file name, so the double quotes are needed (try your function with a file called `*` in a directory containing other files).

Comment: the '*' is globbed by the shell (zsh in my case) and expanded before they hit the function. `fp *` yields `/tmp/4cc3ea0c1b34b` since thats the first paramete for the function. the other parameters would be the other files in the directory. as soon as i have a file called '*' the function still works as expected, calling it with "*" or \* or *

Comment: bash is the "bad" one here as it seems, bash yields what you are refering to.

Comment: @akira: Bash follows the standard behavior. Zsh is the odd one out, removing the need for double-quoting almost everything thanks to a better design but one that's incompatible with existing sh scripts (sh `$foo` corresponds to zsh `$=~foo`, while sh `"$foo"` corresponds to zsh `$foo`).